# How can i parse a comma delimited string into a list (caveat)?

Tags: python, split, escaping, quotes

I need to be able to take a string like:

```
'''foo, bar, "one, two", three four'''
```

into:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'one, two', 'three four']
```

I have an feeling (with hints from #python) that the solution is going to involve the shlex module.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The shlex module solution allows escaped quotes, one quote escape another, and all fancy stuff shell supports.

```
>>> import shlex
>>> my_splitter = shlex.shlex('''foo, bar, "one, two", three four''', posix=True)
>>> my_splitter.whitespace += ','
>>> my_splitter.whitespace_split = True
>>> print list(my_splitter)
['foo', 'bar', 'one, two', 'three', 'four']
```

escaped quotes example:

```
>>> my_splitter = shlex.shlex('''"test, a",'foo,bar",baz',bar \xc3\xa4 baz''',
                              posix=True) 
>>> my_splitter.whitespace = ',' ; my_splitter.whitespace_split = True 
>>> print list(my_splitter)
['test, a', 'foo,bar",baz', 'bar \xc3\xa4 baz']
```

Comment: This splits up the three and four, which is not in the specification.

Comment: Needs a fix for splitting the final "three four".

Comment: Simply changing my_splitter.whitespace += ',' to = ',' will do it, but you still need to strip each element.

Comment: Unfortunately shlex ignores blank values. So 'a,,b' returns ['a', 'b'], not the desired ['a', '', 'b']

Comment: @DRead yeah you have to quote empty strings, so "a,'',b" would return what you want.

Comment: 15 years later `print list(my_splitter)` isn't accepted syntax

Answer (score 42):

It depends how complicated you want to get... do you want to allow more than one type of quoting.  How about escaped quotes?

Your syntax looks very much like the common CSV file format, which is supported by the Python standard library:

```
import csv
reader = csv.reader(['''foo, bar, "one, two", three four'''], skipinitialspace=True)
for r in reader:
  print r
```

Outputs:

```
['foo', 'bar', 'one, two', 'three four']
```

HTH!

Comment: Yeah, the csv module is totally what you want here.

Comment: Just tested this and it works a treat. More straightforward syntax than the shlex module, so this gets my vote!

Answer (score 5):

You may also want to consider the [csv](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-csv.html) module. I haven't tried it, but it looks like your input data is closer to CSV than to shell syntax (which is what shlex parses).

Comment: Agreed. Minus the enclosing ''' portions, that looks like pretty standard CSV formatting. (Well, as much as it can, without a CSV standard.)

Comment: @jdmichal: The ''' is just a way to quote strings in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'\s*("[^"]*"|.*?)\s*,')
>>> def split(line):
...  return [x[1:-1] if x[:1] == x[-1:] == '"' else x
...          for x in pattern.findall(line.rstrip(',') + ',')]
... 
>>> split("foo, bar, baz")
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
>>> split('foo, bar, baz, "blub blah"')
['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'blub blah']
```

Comment: 15 years later this still works while the higher ranked solutions do not.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say a regular expression would be what you're looking for here, though I'm not terribly familiar with Python's Regex engine.

Assuming you use lazy matches, you can get a set of matches on a string which you can put into your array.

Answer (score -2):

If it doesn't need to be pretty, this might get you on your way:

```
def f(s, splitifeven):
    if splitifeven & 1:
        return [s]
    return [x.strip() for x in s.split(",") if x.strip() != '']

ss = 'foo, bar, "one, two", three four'

print sum([f(s, sie) for sie, s in enumerate(ss.split('"'))], [])
```