# How can I join a list into a string (caveat)?

Tags: python, string, list, csv

Along the lines of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118096/how-can-i-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-into-a-list-caveat), how can i join a list of strings into a string such that values get quoted cleanly. Something like:

```
['a', 'one "two" three', 'foo, bar', """both"'"""]
```

into:

```
a, 'one "two" three', "foo, bar", "both\"'"
```

I suspect that the csv module will come into play here, but i'm not sure how to get the output I want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the `csv` module you can do that way:

```
import csv
writer = csv.writer(open("some.csv", "wb"))
writer.writerow(the_list)
```

If you need a string just use `StringIO` instance as a file:

```
f = StringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(the_list)
print f.getvalue()
```

The output: `a,"one ""two"" three","foo, bar","both""'"`

`csv` will write in a way it can read back later.
You can fine-tune its output by defining a `dialect`, just set `quotechar`, `escapechar`, etc, as needed:

```
class SomeDialect(csv.excel):
    delimiter = ','
    quotechar = '"'
    escapechar = "\\"
    doublequote = False
    lineterminator = '\n'
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

f = cStringIO.StringIO()
writer = csv.writer(f, dialect=SomeDialect)
writer.writerow(the_list)
print f.getvalue()
```

The output: `a,one \"two\" three,"foo, bar",both\"'`

The same dialect can be used with csv module to read the string back later to a list.

Answer (score 2):

On a related note, Python's [builtin encoders](http://docs.python.org/lib/standard-encodings.html) can also do string escaping:

```
>>> print "that's interesting".encode('string_escape')
that\'s interesting
```

Comment: +1 although this, in itself, isn't what i was looking for, i can see this being very helpful to me at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly simpler alternative.

```
def quote(s):
    if "'" in s or '"' in s or "," in str(s):
        return repr(s)
    return s
```

We only need to quote a value that might have commas or quotes.

```
>>> x= ['a', 'one "two" three', 'foo, bar', 'both"\'']
>>> print ", ".join( map(quote,x) )
a, 'one "two" three', 'foo, bar', 'both"\''
```