# Python's ConfigParser unique keys per section

Tags: python, configuration-files

I read the part of [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html) and saw that the `ConfigParser` returns a list of key/value pairs for the options within a section. I figured that keys did not need to be unique within a section, otherwise the parser would just return a mapping. I designed my config file schema around this assumption, then sadly realized that this is not the case:

```
>>> from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
>>> from StringIO import StringIO
>>> fh = StringIO("""
... [Some Section]
... spam: eggs
... spam: ham
... """)
>>> parser = ConfigParser()
>>> parser.readfp(fh)
>>> print parser.items('Some Section')
[('spam', 'ham')]
```

Then I went back and found the part of the docs that I *should* have read:

> Sections are normally stored in a
>   builtin dictionary. An alternative
>   dictionary type can be passed to the
>   ConfigParser constructor. For example,
>   if a dictionary type is passed that
>   sorts its keys, the sections will be
>   sorted on write-back, as will be the
>   keys within each section.

To keep my existing configuration file scheme (which I really like now ;) I'm thinking of passing a mapping-like object as mentioned above that accumulates values instead of clobbering them. Is there a simpler way to prevent key/value collapse that I'm missing? Instead of making a crazy adapter (that could break if `ConfigParser`'s implementation changes) should I just write a variant of the `ConfigParser` itself?

I feel like this may be one of those 'duh' moments where I'm only seeing the difficult solutions.

**[Edit:]** Here's a more precise example of how I'd like to use the same key multiple times:

```
[Ignored Paths]
ignore-extension: .swp
ignore-filename: tags
ignore-directory: bin
```

I dislike the comma-delimited-list syntax because it's hard on the eyes when you scale it to many values; for example, a comma delimited list of fifty extensions would not be particularly readable.

Comment: I think using lists would be more readable than 50 lines of 'ignore-extension:...'

Comment: Really? I disagree... with each on a separate line you can just scan down the list -- I've never found comma delimited lists of three-letter extensions to be pretty. I also anticipate people wanting to easily comment any given option out, which separate lines is conducive to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ConfigParser isn't designed to handle such conditions. Furthermore, your config file doesn't make sense to me.

ConfigParser gives you a dict-like structure for each section, so when you call parser.items(section), I'm expecting similar output to dict.items(), which is just a list of key/value tuples. I would never expect to see something like:

```
[('spam', 'eggs'), ('spam', 'ham')]
```

Not to mention, how would you expect the following to behave?:

```
parser.get('Some Section', 'spam')
```

Which is the intended way to retrieve values.

If you want to store multiple values for the same key, I would suggest something like this in your config file:

```
[Some Section]
spam: eggs, ham
```

And this in your code:

```
spam_values = [v.strip() for v in parser.get('Some Section', 'spam').split(',')]
```

Of course, this will only work for values that don't contain commas themselves or handle quoting. For that, you should employ a more advanced technique (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118096/how-can-i-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-into-a-list-caveat) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118458/how-can-i-join-a-list-into-a-string-caveat)).

EDIT: If you don't mind the extra dependency, You could check out [ConfigObj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html), which natively supports lists as a value type.

Comment: I would expect `parser.get` to return either the first or the last value associated with the key. I was hoping that the configuration was stored *internally* as items. I dislike the list syntax because it's more difficult to eyeball, but I may have to switch.

Comment: I'm speculating, but I think a dict would be a more efficient base class for a section. If this is the case, it would explain the behavior. Either way, you're going to give yourself one hell of a headache trying to make it do what you want.

Comment: Fair enough. I have enough headaches as-is. :)

Answer (score 0):

This deficiency of ConfigParser is the reason why pyglet used [patched version of epydoc](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/diff?spec=svnffc4fe58bc2179a75d3338aa821eb04649609871&old=95d2cfa3167ddd5ca7eb0cd25c277902370fd7f1&r=ffc4fe58bc2179a75d3338aa821eb04649609871&format=unidiff&path=%2Ftools%2Fepydoc%2Fepydoc%2Fcli.py) to replace ConfigParser ini with this [simple format](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/source/diff?format=unidiff&path=/tools/epydoc.config&r=ffc4fe58bc2179a75d3338aa821eb04649609871&spec=svnffc4fe58bc2179a75d3338aa821eb04649609871):

```
name: pyglet
url: http://www.pyglet.org/

output: html
target: doc/api/
...    
module: pyglet

exclude: pyglet.gl.gl
exclude: pyglet.gl.agl
exclude: pyglet.gl.lib_agl
exclude: pyglet.gl.wgl
...
```

If you don't need sections - this approach can be useful.