# Python ConfigParser Checking existence of both Section and Key Value

Tags: python, key, config, configparser

Using ConfigParser's `has_section()` method I can check if a section exists in a file, such as:

```
config.has_section(section_name)
```

What would be a command to check if a **key** exists as well? 
So it would be possible to verify that both a section and key exists before querying the value using:

```
value = config.get(section, key)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this might help you out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287757/pythons-configparser-unique-keys-per-section

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In addition to `has_section`, there is also a `has_option` method:

```
config.has_option(section, option)
```

From the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html):

> **has_option***(section, option)*
>  If the given section exists, and contains
>   the given option, return True; otherwise return False. If the
>   specified section is None or an empty string, DEFAULT is assumed.