# How to quickly parse a list of strings

Tags: python

If I want to split a list of words separated by a delimiter character, I can use

```
>>> 'abc,foo,bar'.split(',')
['abc', 'foo', 'bar']
```

But how to easily and quickly do the same thing if I also want to handle quoted-strings which can contain the delimiter character ?

```
In: 'abc,"a string, with a comma","another, one"'
Out: ['abc', 'a string, with a comma', 'another, one']
```

Related question: [How can i parse a comma delimited string into a list (caveat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118096/how-can-i-parse-a-comma-delimited-string-into-a-list-caveat)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
import csv

input = ['abc,"a string, with a comma","another, one"']
parser = csv.reader(input)

for fields in parser:
  for i,f in enumerate(fields):
    print i,f    # in Python 3 and up, print is a function; use: print(i,f)
```

Result:

```
0 abc
1 a string, with a comma
2 another, one
```

Comment: Nice one. Smart use of the module :-)

Answer (score 8):

The [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) should be able to do that for you