# Get a list from config.ini file

Tags: python, configparser

In my config file I have something like that :

```
[Section_1]
List=Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4
```

Now, I would like to process it in my main file as normal lists :

```
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read("configTab.ini")
    for index in range(len(List)):
                 sql=sql.replace(List[index],"replace("+List[index]+","'hidden'")")
```

Now when I read from configuration file "List" is a normal String.
What is the best approach to to it?

If I put a normal list variable in my main code it this way:

```
List=['Column1','Column2','Column3','Column4']
```

Then it works fine, but I would like to get that from my configure file,

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list from a config file with ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6759016/getting-a-list-from-a-config-file-with-configparser)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

`List = List.split(',')`

```
string = 'a, b, c'
print(string.split(','))
>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @DeepSpace is not entirely correct.  The leading whitespace around 'b' and 'c' is included in the output if one executes this line as written (e.g. 'b' is actually ' b').

To avoid leading and trailing whitespace, try:

```py
string = 'a, b, c'
print([i.strip() for i in string.split(',')])
>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular expression to remove extra space and split with commas
[re.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
pattern = re.compile("^\s+|\s*,\s*|\s+$")
str_list = 'a, b, c'
cis_list = pattern.split(str_list)
>> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```