# python: unpacking a string to a list

Tags: python, list, unpack

The answer to [a question on multiple-value elements in a config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser) (which exactly fits my needs) suggests to "unpack the string from the config". I read the doc for [unpacking arguments lists](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) suggested in several places but I fail to understand how this relates to my problem.

I am sure this must be obvious: having a string `str = "123,456"`, how can I transform it into the list `[123,456]` (the number of elements separated by a comma in the string may vary)

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. I learned something with the map() function. Also "str" is indeed a bad name for a function, I usually use the thisString version (but Murphy's law dictates that I used "str" when posting worldwide :))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want a list of strings or a list of ints?

If you just want a list of strings, it's very simple:

```
my_list = my_string.split(',')
```

If you want to convert these to ints, you need:

```
my_list = map(int, my_string.split(','))
```

(Also, don't use `str` as a variable name as it shadows the built-in `str()` function.)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any noticeable difference in terms of performance between using `map` or simply the syntax I presented?

Comment: Not really. To be honest, I usually use the list comprehension myself, but typed in `map` this time because it's quicker to type :-)

Answer (score 5):

```
[int(x) for x in str.split(",")]
```

You're basically applying the function `int` to each element produced by split of your string.

The result of simply `str.split(',')` would be `["123","456"]`.

As Daniel Roseman pointed out, you should be careful not to use variable or method names that inadvertently overshadow built in methods, like, for instance, `str`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

```
unpacked = str.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the other answers, you should also handle exceptions in the case of invalid string representation of a supposed number. Take, for example, the following snippet:

```
number_string = "123,456,x21"
delimiter = ","
number_list = []
for item in number_string.split(delimiter):
    try:
        my_num = int(item)
        number_list.append(item)
    except ValueError, e:
        # you can choose to just pass or handle the error like so
        print "Skipping %s: %s" % (item, e.message)
```

Just a thought. Good luck!