# How to create an array or list in a default.conf file

Tags: python, linux, configuration, webserver

I've inherited a python script that is pulling some variables from a default.conf file which I believe is a Machine configuration file.

One of the parts of the script is pulling a configuration key from the .conf file and expecting there to be a list of possible options however right now there is just one option and I'm unsure of how to make it so there are multiple options.

```
[syndication]
name = Test Name
title = Test Title
categories = Category 1
```

So in the above example the config key is `syndication` and the variable I'm trying to add multiple options to is `category`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show is the segment of code that is causing problems?  That will (hopefully) help us to figure out what should be in the conf file.

Comment: If you need to read it with ConfigParser, parsing lists is not build in. My favourite to read in lists is this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9735884/1301710. Maybe you can switch to another config parser or json in general to store and parse your configuration files http://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserShootout

Answer (score 5):

If there are too few values that ​​fit on one line, I would choose to separate them by commas as exemplified by other fellows, otherwise per [RFC822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822.html) standard you can split values by lines started by tabs:

*settings.conf:*

```
[syndication]
name = Test Name
title = Test Title
categories =
    Category 1
    Category 2
    Category 3
```

*settings.py*:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()

# Reading
config.readfp(open('settings.conf'))
categories = config.get('syndication', 'categories').strip().split('\n')

# Appending
categories.append('Category 4')

# Changing
config.set('syndication', 'categories', '\n' + '\n'.join(categories))

# Storing
config.write(open('settings.conf', 'w'))
```

Your new *settings.conf*:

```
[syndication]
name = Test Name
title = Test Title
categories = 
    Category 1
    Category 2
    Category 3
    Category 4
```

*Note:* You can put a value in the first line after the `:` or `=`, but being a list of values, I think starting from the second line is more "readable" when you've to manually edit the file.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have a list type in configuration files. However you can do something like comma delimited values:

```
[syndication]
name = Test Name
title = Test Title
categories = Category 1, Category 2
```

Then in your code split the values by ,

```
values = [value.strip() for value in cfg.get('syndication', 'categories').split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how you're reading the `.conf` file, so I'll assume you're using [`ConfigParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html).

I tried setting `categories` to a tuple and using `ConfigParser.write`, and ended up with a string representation of the tuple in the resulting file. This implies to me that `ConfigParser` doesn't support multiple options.

You can always break up an option manually:

```
categories = [option.strip() for option in config.get('syndication', 'categories').split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is perhaps working the same way as python's [logging configuration file format](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/logging.config.html#configuration-file-format)? In this case `categories` would be a comma separated list (In case of logging configuration files,  every item is referring to a specific section in the config file)