# Making Python list in file and editing it later

Tags: python, list

I'm making an program which stores certain data in txt files. I did it like this and it works, but I want to change it to lists, so it's easier to edit stuff inside with list.remove and list.append... This is format I made:

```
Username:data1:data2:data3:data++
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Username:[data1, data2, data3, data++]
```

Why I want this?

Because editing data separated with ":" is not "Pythonic way" to do this, so I want to convert them to lists...

I get certain lines using this filter:

```
textfile = open("%s/CreativePoints/Data/plotovimemberi.txt"%pluginlokacija2, 'r+')
a = filter(lambda x: x.startswith("%s:%s"%(targetplot, userID)), \
                                          textfile.readlines())
```

So current data file looks like this:

```
Username:data1:data2
Username1:data134:data453:data6534
Username3:data5345:data678:data111:data434
and so on...
```

What I want to achieve is:

```
Username:[data1, data2]
Username1:[data134, data453, data6534]
Username3:[data5345, data678, data111, data434]
and so on...
```

Why? Because I want to get certain line in file using filter I mentioned above and edit list... So I just need to split lines using "line.split(':')[1]" and get list of data, which I can edit using list.append and list.remove...

Thanks for reading/answering! :)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @EmilVikström How to make list in txt file which will contain certain data and get it later so I can edit it? Format is Username:[data1, data2, data3]

Comment: More common way to store objects in files is pickle https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: So what exactly have you tried? What is working/not working?

Comment: @BasicWolf I made so it separates data with ":" but as I said, it's not Pythonic way to do it, so I want to remove : between "data" and implement lists inside...

Comment: @AlexeyShestakov I'm not sure how it works, how do I save pickle inside txt file, how do I read it, how do I remove/append data?

Answer (score 1):

While I think I've given one answer to your question (see code below), I have some remarks:

- it's not 'unpythonic' to use a colon as a separator in text file; that's not Python, that's data.
- you should look at something like YAML or JSON to store your data; you can then use libraries that take care of most of the details for you
- with the scheme you propose, you won't be able to have a "," in your data records, nor (simply) be able to start or end records with space.  These sorts of problems should be handled for you by any reasonable JSON or YAML library.
- you could also look at something like sqlite (which comes with python) as a database store.  It's a bit more work, but you'll be able to search for records based on criteria of your choosing, as well as easily delete and add records.  With a plain-text file, you'll have to manage all of that yourself

Here's my solution:

```
from pprint import pprint

def writefile(outfilename,db):
    outfile=open(outfilename,'wt')
    for username,userdata in db:
        userdatastr= ','.join(userdata)
        outfile.write('%s: [%s]\n' % (username,userdatastr))
    # or, better, use 'with file("...") as ...'
    outfile.close()

def readfile(infilename):
    infile=open(infilename,'rt')
    db=[]
    for line in infile:
        username, rest = line.split(':',1)
        lstart= rest.find('[')
        if lstart==-1:
            raise RuntimeError('couldn''t find "[" for user "%s"' % username)
        lend= rest.rfind(']')
        if lend==-1:
            raise RuntimeError('couldn''t find "]" for user "%s"' % username)
        userdata = rest[lstart+1:lend].split(',')
        db.append((username,userdata))
    return db

db=[('Bob',['foo','bar','baz']),
    ('Jane',['oof','rab','zab','xuuq']),
    ('Rudy',['some','data'])]

writefile('db.txt',db)

indb=readfile('db.txt')

print 'original:'
pprint(db)
print 'from file:'
pprint(indb)
```

Result is:

```
 original:
 [('Bob', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']),
  ('Jane', ['oof', 'rab', 'zab', 'xuuq']),
  ('Rudy', ['some', 'data'])]
 from file:
 [('Bob', ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']),
  ('Jane', ['oof', 'rab', 'zab', 'xuuq']),
  ('Rudy', ['some', 'data'])]
```

while db.txt looks like:

```
Bob: [foo,bar,baz]
Jane: [oof,rab,zab,xuuq]
Rudy: [some,data]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about ConfigParser https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html. This library can solve your problem with reading and writing. You can read here more about using lists in ConfigParser -> [Lists in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [pickle](https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle) or [pyyaml](http://pyyaml.org/) to store your objects in text files. Example of using pickle:

```
import pickle
# save some list
lst=['hello','pickle']
pickle.dump(lst, open('lst.txt','w'))
# load list from txt file
lst2=pickle.load(open('lst.txt'))
print(lst2)
```

If you want to store data in readable form you could use pyyaml:

```
from yaml import load, dump
# dump list in readable form
lst=['hello', 'yaml']
open('lst2.txt', 'w').write(dump(lst))
# load list from yaml file
print(load(open('lst2.txt')))
```

Comment: Pickles look nice but this will return me everything from that file right? I need to get only certain lines in that file like I did using "filter" I put above... Read bottom of question above, I gave explanation on how data is stored and how I want to store it...

Answer (score 0):

Edited accordingly:

```
list = [data1, data2, data3, data++]

file = open("file.txt", "w")
file.write("Username: " + str(list))
file.close
```

Comment: Nope, I already did that, what I want is to use lists to store data, not to separate each data with ":"...

Comment: I've edited it for you

Comment: It's clear to me, but for example, I want to add more data to list that is in file.txt, how do I do that?

Comment: @user3557637 `list.append(data2++)` or whatever

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a dictionary, not a list, unless the Username is not unique, where you could use a list.

```
data_text = '''Username1:data1:data2:data3:data++
Username2:data1:data2:data3:data++
Username3:data1:data2:data3:data++
Username3:data4:data5:data6:data++'''

lines = data_text.split('\n')

data_dict = {}
data_list = []
for l in lines:
    fields = l.split(':')
    user = fields[0]
    data = fields[1:]
    data_dict[user] = data
    data_list.append((user,data))

print(data_text)
print(data_dict)
print(data_list)
```

Comment: Usernames are unique... Every line contains data for one user...