# How can I take several variable from config at the same time?

Tags: python, config

I'm setting up a script where I need to take several variable from my config at the same time. I've set my config as: `config = configparser.ConfigParser()`.

I've tried to take these variables using `*` symbol.

```py
[part1]
variable1 = 10
variable2 = 20
```

I've tried to take it with:

```py
variable = config.get('part1', 'variable*')
```

but this way doesn't work.

I search a way to realize that, in order to get it into a list for example.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's `config`? A dictionary?

Comment: the `get` method will only return one value. And what should `variable` be? a list? the first value found? a dictionnary?

Comment: if it is a dictionary you can use the dict comprehension

Comment: Do you not know how to get the individual variables, or how to know what the variables are, or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lists in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser)

Comment: @Rightleg my `config` is just another script where I have all my configuration variables, I'll update my question.

Comment: @olinox14 `variable` is just a string that I want to return. In fact, I want to get all the variable which begins by the string `variable` in order to get `variable1` and `variable2`.

Comment: @ScottHunter I know how I can get variable by variable but I search a way to obtain all the variables which begin by `variable` (for example) in a single list.

Comment: @KaiesLAMIRI this is not a dict.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
cfg_items = config.items('part1')
```

to get all the configs in the section.

Then filter the dictionary keys using the regex you defined.

You can do it in a single step

```
cfg_list = [val for var, val in config.items('part1') if var.startswith('variable')]
```

Comment: The single-step line is exactly what I want. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would just use a list comprehension to iterate over the variables you want.

```
to_get = ('variable1', 'variable2')
values = [config.get('part1', x) for x in to_get]
```

The problem with `variable*` is that it assumes the config file will only contain the options you *expect*. Be explicit, and only fetch the ones you want.

`ConfigParser` supports the mapping protocol in Python 3.2 or later:

```
values = [config['part1'][x] for x in to_get]
```

which opens the door for using `operator.itemgetter` as well. Said use can range from ugly to useful, depending on how you refactor. The straightforward approach would look like

```
values = operator.itemgetter(*to_get)(config['part1'])
```

Comment: In my case, I'm trying to establish something configurable. How can I use this method If I don't know how many `variable` I have in my `part1` for example?

Comment: I would redesign your configuration so the that you *do* know how many variables there are. Require something like `variable_count = 3`, then you know that `variable1`, `variable2`, and `variable3` are to be read. If that's not an option, just start sequentially reading variables until you hit one that does not exist.

Comment: Better yet, use a better file format that supports lists. (JSON, YAML, TOML, dhall, etc)