# Reading the section from a config File in Python(2.7) as a dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a config file with the  below section

```
[TEST]

fruit=["apple","select * from apple"]
vegetable=["carrot","select * from carrot"]
```

I am trying to load the section into a python dictionary using the below code

```
   config=ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
   config.optionxform =str
   cofigPath='/home/ini/target.ini'
   config.read(configPath)
```

Now , when i am trying to load the section into a dictionary , i am not getting the list in the value , instead its getting stored as a String

```
   tabList=dict(config.items('TEST'))
   for k, v in tableList.iteritems():
       print(k,v[0])
```

The v[0] is not printing "apple" , instead its taking the value section of teh dictionary as a string and printing v[0] as "[" , the first character of the value of the dictionary.

Please suggest what i should incorporate to read the section into dictionary where i can  get the list as the value when i iterate over the dictionary

Comment: `.ini` file don't support this well.  Consider to use other format: json, toml, yaml...

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11866695/75103

Comment: @thebjorn..no it does not work for my case