# How to convert a list to string when retrieved from a config file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to search for few strings from the logline and exclude those lines.
If I try with string directly it works but if I read the strings from a config file, it doesn't.
The problem is due to the type. Can someone put some light into this in converting the list to string?

Code

```
match1 = config.get('sky_messages', 'matches')
match = list(match1.split(","))

print(match1)
print(match)
print(type(match1))
print(type(match))
```

Config File

```
[sky_messages]
matches = ['Conviva', 'conviva', 'EDID', 'CONVIVA']
```

Output

```
['Conviva', 'conviva', 'EDID', 'CONVIVA']
["['Conviva'", " 'conviva'", " 'EDID'", " 'CONVIVA']"]
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```

How can I get the string as match1?

Comment: I don't know if its the best solution but you could use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Basically, i need to convert that list to string exactly as match1.

Comment: Why do you have it as python syntax in the config file? Can you just use a comma seperated list of values?

Comment: Thats the requirement to have it in a config file. I have few more sections in the config file.

Comment: Particularly with the duplicate, check the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9735884/1324033)