# How to use the writerow function in Python

Tags: python, csv, configparser

Im using csv to write rows to an empty text file, but when I open the textfile I see there is a space between each letter/character. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

**This is my code:**

```
import csv
import configparser

# Read local `config.ini` file.
config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                     
config.read(r'C:\data\FF\Desktop\Studio\cfg.ini')

header_1= config['HEADERS']['headers_1']
header_2 =config['HEADERS']['headers_2']

full_path = r'C:\data\FF\Desktop\Studio\New Text Document.txt' 

with open(full_path, 'w') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(header_1)
    writer.writerow(header_2)
```

**This is how cfg.ini looks like:**

```
[HEADERS]
headers_2 = ['VEHICLE', 'MODEL', 'DSG', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE','SECOND']

headers_1 = ['*****data*****']
```

**This is how New Text Document.txt looks like:**
[image]

Comment: The problem is not the `csv.writerow`, but how you read the list from `cfg.ini`. You read string, not list (as you think). And to fix the extra blank line - check https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348460/4046632

Comment: @buran okay the blank line is solved now, but the string/list story not.

Comment: Did you check the link in my first comment?

Comment: Yes, but could not solve it.

Comment: import `json`, then `header_1 = json.loads(config['HEADERS']['headers_1'])`. That is assuming you don't change the current format in `cfg.ini`, only replace `'` with `"` (double quotes, not 2 single-quotes)

Comment: Thank you. If you can place that in an answer I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the `csv.writerow`, but how you read the list from `cfg.ini`. You read string, not list (as you think). Check [Lists in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser)
And to fix the extra blank line (when using csv module on windows) you need to specify `newline=''` - check [CSV file written with Python has blank lines between each row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3348460/4046632)

cfg.ini

```
[HEADERS]
headers_2 = ["VEHICLE", "MODEL", "DSG", "YEAR", "MONTH", "DAY", "HOUR", "MINUTE","SECOND"]
headers_1 = ["*****data*****"]
```

your file:

```
import csv
import configparser
import json

# Read local `config.ini` file.
config = configparser.ConfigParser()                                     
config.read(r'C:\data\FF\Desktop\Studio\cfg.ini')

header_1 = json.loads(config['HEADERS']['headers_1'])
header_2 = json.loads(config['HEADERS']['headers_2'])

full_path = r'C:\data\FF\Desktop\Studio\New Text Document.txt' 

with open(full_path, 'w', newline='') as output:
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = '\t')
    writer.writerow(header_1)
    writer.writerow(header_2)
```

Comment: your question should be closed as [double] duplicate, not upvoted. I post the answer, only to avoid any misunderstanding from my advise in the comments.

Comment: @buran I think he is right, the question you tagged is not that clear. We also need to respect the way mediterraneo asked his question, very clear in what is he looking for.

Comment: Could not agree more with @NorthAfrican, this question is very clear and we see exactly what he wants. Deserves nothing but respect and an upvote obviously. (despite a bit of duplication with your link) Lot of developers can learn from the way this question is asked.