# Parsing multiple values for a key with ConfigParser using delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x, configparser

I'm trying to parse a list of values for a key using ConfigParser in Python 3.

I saw that it is possible using the JSON library and Python lists in the config file ([Lists in ConfigParser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335695/lists-in-configparser)):

```
[sites]
urls = ["https://google.com", "https://yahoo.com", "https://gmail.com"]
```

Is it possible to set a delimiter instead? Example, using a colon delimiter:

```
[sites]
urls=https\://google.com:https\://yahoo.com:https\://gmail.com
```

Comment: This needs a regular expression or other more involved solutions.

Comment: You could use a regex like `(?<!\\):` to split this. ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HAUYbp/1))

Comment: Using regex was the way. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply [split](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) on a separator of your choice applicable for your list of URLs, e.g.:

```
import configparser

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = configparser.ConfigParser()
    parser.read_string("""
    [sites]
    urls=https://google.com;https://yahoo.com;https://gmail.com
    """)

    sites = parser['sites']['urls'].split(';')
    print(sites)  # prints ['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://gmail.com']
```

Keep in mind that semicolons might be part of URLs. Therefore, a different separator might be a better choice for you.

Comment: This works but does not deal with the backslash escaping for characters that I want to keep.

Comment: What I wanted was a more Perlish/Linux-style config file (I'm new to Python).

Answer (score 0):

Based on [oschlueter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3388491/oschlueter)'s answer and [Nick ODell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/530160/nick-odell)'s comment, the following does the job:

```py
[s.replace('\\','') for s in re.split(r'(?<!\\):', parser['sites']['urls'])]
```

`re.split` [returns the capture group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) – the negative lookbehind in this case – so you need to remove it with `str.replace`.

```py
>>> import re
>>> from configparser import ConfigParser
>>> parser = ConfigParser()
>>> parser.read('config.ini')
['config.ini']
>>> [s.replace('\\','') for s in re.split(r'(?<!\\):', parser['sites']['urls'])]
['https://google.com', 'https://yahoo.com', 'https://gmail.com']
```

EDIT:

Works with other delimiters too:

```py
urls_at=https://google.com/\@@https://yahoo.com/\@@https://gmail.com/\@
urls_semicolon=https://google.com/\;;https://yahoo.com/\;;https://gmail.com/\;
```

```py
>>> [s.replace('\\','') for s in re.split(r'(?<!\\);', parser['sites']['urls_semicolon'])]
['https://google.com/;', 'https://yahoo.com/;', 'https://gmail.com/;']
>>> [s.replace('\\','') for s in re.split(r'(?<!\\)@', parser['sites']['urls_at'])]
['https://google.com/@', 'https://yahoo.com/@', 'https://gmail.com/@']
```